# Mixed effects GLM for summary data

Tags: regression, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme

I have experimental data in which I grew two types of bacteria, 3 samples for each, in multiple plates, and then obtained summary of colony counts. Unfortunately, I do not have the counts per plate but rather the number of plates for three intervals of the number of colonies:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(sample = rep(c(paste0("A",1:3),paste0("B",1:3)),3),
                 group = rep(c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)),3),
                 min.count = c(rep(0,6),rep(2,6),rep(5,6)),
                 max.count = c(rep(0,6),rep(4,6),rep(9,6)),
                 number.plates = round(runif(18,1000,10000)))
```

Hence, for example, for bacteria `A` from sample `A1` I obtained 3390 plates having exactly 0 colonies, 9502 plates having between 2 and 4 colonies, and 7183 plates having between 5 and 9 colonies.

What I'd like to test for is whether the two bacteria groups have different number of colonies, accounting for the sample variation.

Ideally, I would have the raw data and probably fit a `poisson` mixed-effects `GLM`. But since I don't I guess two of my options are:

1. For each row `i` in `df`, sample `df$number.plates[i]` from a `uniform` between `df$min.count[i]` and `max.count[i]`, round the samples, and then fit the mixed-effects poisson `GLM` to that. For the counts I have using lme4::glm is very slow.
2. Compare the counts for each count interval, between the two groups, with a multinomial regression (in `R` using `nnet::multinom`). That would not account for sample variation.

Any idea what's favorable between the two and if there are any better options?

Comment: what kind of experiment is this where you have 100,000+ plates? Robotic?

Comment: Yep. But it also applies to an automated dot-counting data in cells (dots are gene transcripts in the cell imaged using a microscope). So colonies = dots and plates = cells.